# Pandas: what is a NDFrame object (and what is a non-NDFrame object)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concat two DataFrames and am getting a `'TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object'` error. I have been looking around, there are a lot of people getting this error, most of the time when they try to do something other than what their code really does, (so the answers solve their particular but unrelated questions)

My question is not to solve my particular problem, but to understand the error...
What is a non-NDFrame object? Why can it not be concatenated?

Also, why is this about NDFrames (What are those, and where do I use them? Are all DataFrames NDFrames? Are there any NDFrames that are not DataFrames?)...

I would understand if it said `'TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-DataFrame object'` (though I am not sure if them not being DataFrames was the cause of my error) This is mainly my curiosity questing, I am not trying to hunt any specific bug...

Comment: it probably means you're trying to concatenate a bunch of `Series`, a NDFrame means N-dimensional so at least 2-D a series is 1-D, the issue here is that you're trying to concatenate and align on index and column names. A series has an index but no column name (there is a name attribute but this is not the same), it could be made to work but the implementation doesn't support this

Comment: Or you're passing something whose type is not a ND-Frame, for example a numpy array, actually concatenating a list of pandas Series will work. You'll need to post raw data and code to demonstrate what you're trying

Comment: *me embarrassed* I fixed the code and now cannot seem to reproduce my error, so it might well be what you write... My question though is not about my error, rather what is an NDFrame object... There seems to be no question about it, in stackoverflow. It seems to me that DataFrame is an NDFrame (?) Googling I get that "pandas.core.generic.NDFrame
is an N-dimensional analogue of DataFrame that stores multi-dimensional in a size-mutable, labeled data structure", but would like to have a more fleshed explanation about what it is what it does, what it is not, and its relation to DataFrame...

Comment: Just think of it as N-Dimensional arrays, nothing more complicated than that

Comment: For anyone else finding this page in their search results, if you're getting this error from pd.concat after passing it the variable name of a list of dataframes, double-check that you haven't surrounded that variable name with brackets (which would create a list of lists, which is a non-NDFrame object)

Comment: In my case, It worked when I removed single quotes around data-frame name.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[From the horse's mouth:](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L94)

> N-dimensional analogue of DataFrame. Store multi-dimensional in a size-mutable, labeled data structure

[Then what's a DataFrame?](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L204)

> class DataFrame(NDFrame):
>    Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data
>       structure with labeled axes (rows and columns). Arithmetic operations
>       align on both row and column labels. Can be thought of as a dict-like
>       container for Series objects.

As you can see, a DataFrame is a subclass (i.e. special case) of NDFrame.  In Pandas programs generally, DataFrame is used a lot and NDFrame is used rarely.  In fact, Pandas has Series for 1D, DataFrame for 2D, and for most people that's the end, even though half of Pandas' name is for `Panel` which [Pandas also has](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html), but most people do not use.

There is/was even a 4D thing in Pandas, but truly no one uses it (this being the internet, someone will now appear to say they do!).  For higher dimensions than two or maybe three, some people have shifted their efforts to [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/).  That's probably where it's at if your ambitions cannot be contained in 2D.

Comment: Wow! 3 years and nobody came to say "I use 4D arrays". Impressive.

Comment: `Panel` was removed in v1.0 apparently, after being [deprecated in v0.20](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#deprecate-panel)