# Append values to Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I am selecting values from an SQL database through pandas, but when I want to add new values to the existing pandas series, I receive a "cannt concatenate a non-NDframe object". So I am not really sure how I should proceed.

```
sql = "select * from table"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
datovalue = df['Datovalue']
datovalue.append(35)
```

This is is how the datovalues look like when i print it out:

```
0   736722.0 

1   736722.0 

2  736723.0  

3  736723.0 

4   736725.0
```

How do add an extra (**5th index** in this case) value?

Comment: Can you make an example we can run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: what is a NDFrame object (and what is a non-NDFrame object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973200/pandas-what-is-a-ndframe-object-and-what-is-a-non-ndframe-object)

Comment: it's just a normal dataframe with index 0,1,2... and then corresponding values to each index. And I want to add extra values to the series.

Comment: Your Dimensions of Dataframe are wrong.

Comment: how do i fix it? Because i am literrally just taking values from an sql table column and trying to add new values on top of it.

Comment: for append DF type must be same . this is not normal list. you need to use `datovalue.append({'<column name>': 35}, ignore_index=True)

Comment: refer [this link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Comment: Did you try `datovalue.append([35])`

Comment: yeah it worked with manually created frame. like below posted answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several equivalent ways to add data to a series by index:

```
s = pd.Series([736722.0, 736722.0, 736723.0, 736723.0, 736725.0])

# direct indexing
s[5] = 35

# loc indexing
s.loc[5] = 35

# loc indexing with unknown index
s.loc[s.index.max()+1] = 35

# append with series
s = s.append(pd.Series([35], index=[5]))

# concat with series
s = pd.concat([s, pd.Series([35], index=[5])])

print(s)

0    736722.0
1    736722.0
2    736723.0
3    736723.0
4    736725.0
5        35.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Which one is the fastest for big type integers?

Comment: Note that `append` is now [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append) and has been removed in pandas 2.0.0, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) should be used as replacement.

Answer (score 0):

just use this

datovalue.append([35])

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5],[3]])
df.append([1])
df
   0

0  5

1  3

0  1
```